# How to use a query returning integers in an SQL function that returns integer[]?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, sql-function

I created a function that returns all values that meet the condition specified and tried specifying `int[]` as the result type of the function.

```
create or replace function mults_of_3_5(id int) returns int[] language sql as
$$
SELECT ValuesUnder1000
FROM Mults
WHERE (ValuesUnder1000 % 3 = 0) or (ValuesUnder1000 % 5 = 0);
$$;
```

I got the error

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return integer[]
DETAIL:  Actual return type is integer.
CONTEXT:  sql function "mults_of_3_5"
```

The data type of `ValuesUnder1000` is `integer`.

When I use the same query outside the function, all the values in the column that satisfies the condition are listed.

Please tell me what I can do to return an array in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The statement returns data types depending on table or function definitions.

Comment: It would be great if you could paste code as text, not as pictures. It's searchable and easier to work with. Also the error message said it all: *function declared to return `integer[]`...Actual return type is `integer`*. Lots of integers being returned from the base query means that it `returns setof integer` or `returns table (column1 integer)`. An array would be a single row and value with all of those `integers` packed inside.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pg_typeof`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.29.1.1.1) to check your data types:

```sql
select valuesunder1000, pg_typeof(valuesunder1000)
from mults
where (valuesunder1000 % 5 = 0) or (valuesunder1000 % 3 = 0);
```

Your function `returns setof int`. If you want it to return an `int[]` array instead, you need to assemble that array. [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.2.1.1.1) can help

```sql
create or replace function mults_of_3_5 (id int) returns int[] as $f$
select array_agg(valuesunder1000)
from mults
where (valuesunder1000 % 5 = 0) or (valuesunder1000 % 3 = 0);
$f$ language sql;
```

It's also possible to use `returns table (valuesunder1000 int)`. Refer to [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) for details on how to build functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a set-returning function (SRF):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mults_of_3_5() RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT ValuesUnder1000
               FROM Mults
               WHERE (ValuesUnder1000 % 3 = 0) OR (ValuesUnder1000 % 5 = 0);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tested it as follows and it seems it works:

```
CREATE TABLE Mults (ValuesUnder1000 integer);

INSERT INTO Mults (ValuesUnder1000) VALUES (3), (5), (9), (10), (12), (15);

SELECT * FROM mults_of_3_5();
```